# Remove the last characters from image source

Tags: jquery, wordpress, image, resolution, src

I'm building a Wordpress site which contains lots of heavy images. 
By loading the 'large' version of the images that wordpress generates I think I can minimize the page load instead of getting the full size of them. But on desktops I want the full sized images to be loaded instead of the 'large' sized ones.

I've used the following code to change the image source if the page is loaded on a desktop:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', src.replace(/-1024x682(\.[^.]+)?$/, '$1'));
});
```

But since all pictures aren't 1024x682 in their 'large' resolution I need another solution to my problem. Is it possible to instead of replacing `-1024x682` in the image src, just remove the last 9 characters (before the file extension of course)?

Comment: Give an example of `src` and the updated `src`

Comment: 'large' src = https://wordpress.axelboberg.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/2-1024x682.jpg and full src = https://wordpress.axelboberg.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/2.jpg

Comment: This will not be reliable no matter how you modify via javascript - consider a file that was already called 'a-1024x682.jpg' and had those dimensions when you uploaded it (wordpress won't create a "large" thumbnail for it, but instead use the original, and when you do the switch you end up with a file that doesn't exist)... You should fetch the alternative image source in php using wordpress functions, so show us the code that actually inserts the image and we'll be able to provide a reliable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your code to something like below

```
var src = $(this).attr('src');
var extension = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf(".")); // gets the extension
var imageName = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf(".")); // gets the file name
imageName = imageName.replace(imageName.substring(imageName.length-9), ""); // replace the last 9 characters with empty string
$(this).attr('src', imageName + extension);
```

Comment: Not reliable - an if the length of the image dimension string including the leading dash is not exactly 9 characters it will not work.

Comment: OP asked to remove 9 characters.

Comment: I'm only going to use the code on images that's uploaded as an attachment, and all those images has got the large attribution to them which adds the nine characters at the end of the src.

Comment: That's true... Other people will come to SO looking for solutions though, so it would be more helpful to provide a solution that won't break in a lot of cases, even though the OP didn't realize this issue when posting his question.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a regex:

```
$(this).attr('src', src.replace(/-[0-9x]+(?=\.jpg)$/, ''));
```

This would allow any numbers/size resolution.